# JQuery Submit and Facebook login

Tags: jquery, facebook, authentication

Howdy, I have a form. When users click on submit, if they are not logged in already a box pops up to log in w/ Facebook. Problem is in the mean time the form data is being posted w/ waiting for the user to actually login. Here is the javascript, you can also view the page at goodsally.com Any help is appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('textarea#goal').focus(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});

$('#postGoals').submit( function()  {

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        // user successfully logged in
    } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                // user successfully logged in
            } else {
                // user cancelled login
            }
            });
    }
    });

})

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `return false;` at the end of your `submit()` event.

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle this manually in your case and add change the

```
$('#postGoals').submit( function()  {
```

to

```
$('#postGoals').submit( function(e)  {
```

followed by

```
  e.preventDefault();
```

so that this event won't be handled without your explicit consent.